# Catel 4 (Prerelease), ReSharper 8.2, .NET 4.5

Tags: catel

ReSharper 8.2 indicates lots of errors in my Catel 4 viewmodels in VS 2012 Update 4 when targeting .NET 4.5. Catel 4.0.0-unstable0463 is installed.

In every VM, derived from ViewModelBase, Re# gives me "Cannot resolve symbol" on every occurrence of GetValue, SetValue, and RegisterProperty. I get the same error when trying to reference WindowLogic.PropertyChanged.

Re# errors go away when I select .NET 4.5.1.

Project was created for 4.5, and NuGet used to install packages.

.NET 4.0 is also clean after re-installing the proper version of Catel.

Thanks.

-reilly.

Comment: Really weird, it must nearly be a ReSharper issue. I cannot reproduce this.